# Swift read json from file outside of Application bundle

Tags: json, swift, nsdata, nsurl

I have spent at least 2 hours trying before posting this rather simple question. The following code works when the json file lives inside the the application bundle.

```
if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json") {....
```

I'm reading the json file this way...

```
let myData = try Data(contentsOf: file as URL)
```

I can't access an identical copy of the file from "/Library/Application Support/AppFolder/data.json".

The following doesn't work

```
let filepath = "/Library/Application Support/AppFolder/data.json"
if let file = NSURL(string: filepath) {...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that URLs in the file system must always be created with `NSURL(fileURLWithPath...)` it's recommended to retrieve specific system folders with one the dedicated APIs:

```
let applicationSupportFolderURL = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.ApplicationSupportDirectory,
                                                               inDomain: .LocalDomainMask,
                                                      appropriateForURL: nil,
                                                                 create: false)
let jsonDataURL = applicationSupportFolderURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("AppFolder/data.json")
```

or in Swift 3 (which is pretty much shorter)

```
let applicationSupportFolderURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, 
                                                                in: .localDomainMask, 
                                                    appropriateFor: nil, 
                                                            create: false)
let jsonDataURL = applicationSupportFolderURL.appendingPathComponent("AppFolder/data.json")
```

Or – in iOS 16+ and macOS 13+ – still more convenient

```
let jsonDataURL = URL.applicationSupportDirectory.appending(path: "AppFolder/data.json")
```

Comment: I had to update the syntax to be swift 3 compliant. I then get an error "Value of type URL has no member URLbyAppendingPathComponent."

Comment: This works perfectly but how can I point it to directory "/Volumes/VolumeName/data.json" ?

Comment: An URL on an external volume can be accessed directly: `let jsonDataURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/Volumes/VolumeName/data.json")`

Comment: Your code in the question is doubtless Swift 3, so `URL` must be available. Have you imported `Foundation`?

Comment: You are correct kind sir. I'll try to access the file and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: "your_path")`

`string:` produces an NSURL that represents the string as given. So the string like "http://www.google.com" and the URL represents http://www.google.com.

`fileURLWithPath:` takes a path, not a URL, and produces an NSURL that represents the path using a file:// URL. So if you give it `/foo/bar/baz` the URL would represent `file:///foo/bar/baz`.